# LINQ and Array.Copy

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, multidimensional-array

I have the following:

```
var list = new List<double[]>();
list.Add(new double[] { 300, 12, 22 });
list.Add(new double[] { 310, 13, 23 });
list.Add(new double[] { 320, 14, 24 });
list.Add(new double[] { 330, 15, 25 });
```

I would like to get from this a multidimensional array containing the first 2 columns:

```
double[,] a = { {300,12}, {310,13}, {320,14}, {330,15}}
```

Can I do this using linq? And how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following

```
var a = list.Select(x => new [] { x[0], x[1] }).ToArray();
```

**EDIT**

Didn't realize at first the intent was to get a non-jagged 2d array out of the source.  Unfortunately there isn't really a way to do that with the standard LINQ methods.  They deal mostly in terms of `IEnumerable<T>` and `T[]`.  However there is nothing stopping you from creating a new method which does this

```
    public static T[,] ToMultidimensionArray<T>(this List<T[]> list, int columns)
    {
        var array = new T[list.Count, columns];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            var source = list[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            {
                array[i, j] = source[j];
            }
        }

        return array;
    }
```

Now you can convert the original list with a simple query

```
var a = list.ToMultidimensionArray(2);
```

Comment: This will create a `double[][]` not a `double[,]`.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ and multi-dimensional arrays do not mix well. Array.Copy is not applicable here as well.

Use a traditional `for` loop:

```
double[,] result = new double[list.Count, 2];

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    result[i, 0] = list[i][0];
    result[i, 1] = list[i][1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static T[,] GetColumns<T>(IList<IEnumerable<T>> source, int numColumns)
{
    T[,] output = new T[source.Count, numColumns];

    for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
    {
        int j = 0;
        foreach (T item in source[j].Take(numColumns))
        {
            output[i, j] = item;
            j++;
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Note that in this case if any of the lists contain an array that doesn't have enough values to fill all of the columns you want then they'll be left with default values, it won't throw an exception.  You'll need to check for it and throw one yourself if you want that to happen.

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = list.Select(item => item.Take(2).ToArray()).ToArray();
foreach (var item in array)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", item[0], item[1]);
}
```

Comment: This will create a `double[][]` not a `double[,]`